# Must use angular.js $apply in service and $http

Tags: angularjs

I defined a service named `storeInstance`, but if do not use `apply`, the service will not work. I encountered the same issue when using `$http`.

1) My service must use apply, or nothing happens:

```
 $scope.$apply(
     storeInstance.get({setName:treeNode.name}).$promise.then(
         function(resolve){
             $scope.store = resolve;

             $scope.set.setName = $scope.store.entitySetName;
        },
        function(reject){console.log("get store failed")}
     ));
```

2) `$http` must must use apply, or nothing happens:

```
$scope.$apply(     
    $http({
        url:URL,
        method:"GET"
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.spaceSchemaList = data;
    });
);
```

Why does this happen? Does anybody know?

Comment: Read this can help you: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: but why sometimes I need add $apply to $http but sometimes not

Comment: Please share more code. If you are outside of angular world, you need to call apply